# How to convert a structure to a C pointer in D?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, d

How do I convert a D structure to a C Pointer in D? Something like:

```
struct test {}
void main() {
    auto testv = test();
    randomfunction(cast(cPtr) test);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to us. Could you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to pass the struct's address to the function, use the `&` (address-of) operator to get a pointer to a structure variable:

```
randomFunction(&testv);
```